# iOS 7.1 JavaScriptCore: Can't find variable: Float64Array

Tags: ios, node.js, javascriptcore

I'm using Node.js via [NodeApp](https://github.com/node-app) (using JavaScriptCore)

While i trying to execute simple script:

```
[_context evaluateScript:@"var temp64f = new Float64Array(1);"];
```

i'm getting error:

```
2014-09-30 14:31:43.318 NodeAppDemo[78825:60b] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Float64Array stack: global code
```

Testing on ios simulator 7.1 and ipad air with ios 7.1.

Checked on ios 8 and **it works on ios 8.**

Answer (score 0):

The version of JavaScriptCore bundled with IOS 7.1 does not support typed arrays, the only thing you can do is to bundle your own (current) version of JavaScriptCore.

this might be a starting point: https://github.com/phoboslab/JavaScriptCore-iOS